# How to optimize this query using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Hi good day I am new with Entity Framework. I just wanna to know if there is a way I could improve my implementation. Here are the codes.

```
 public async Task<List<Record>> GetRecordsByBatchId(string batchId, string source)
    {
        List<string> idList = new List<string>();


        //[1] Get all parent ID from table 1 with a filter of source and batchId
        var parentIds= await _context.Set<FirstTable>()
            .Where(a => a.IsActive
                && a.BatchId.Equals(batchId)
                && a.Source.Equals(source)).Select(b => b.ParentId).ToListAsync();

        if (parentIds.Count() == 0)
        {
            return new List<Record>();
        }


        //[2] Query idNumber of each parentId from [1] to SecondTable
        List<long> idNumber = await _context.Set<SecondTable>()
            .Where(a => parentIds.Contains(a.Id))
            .Select(b => b.IdNumber).ToListAsync();


        //[3] Query Record/s that contains idNumber from previous query [2]. it is possible that 1 or 
        //more records has same idNumber
        List<Risk> recordByIdNumber = await _context.Set<SecondTable>()
            .Where(a => idNumber.Contains(a.IdNumber)).ToListAsync();


       //[4] In this part I just want to group the records in [3] by Id number and sort each group 
       //by its endorsementNumber in descending order and return the record with highest endorsement 
       //number for each group 
        return (from record in recordByIdNumber 
                group record by record.IdNumber into g
                orderby g.Key
                select g.OrderByDescending(risk =>risk.EndorsementNumber).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
    }
}
```

The model for the **FirstTable**

```
    public class FirstTable
{
    public Guid? ParentId{ get; set; }
    public string BatchId { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

The model for the **SecondTable**

```
 public class SecondTable
{
    public Guid Id{ get; set; }
    public int EndorsementNumber { get; set; }
    public long IdNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Note: I just include the necessary properties in the model.

This approach is working as expected. I just wanna know if there is a possibility that these queries could be optimized that there is only 1 query for the **SecondTable** table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know a lot about EF so I might be wrong, I think a description of your model is necesary to understand your code.

Comment: Hello @RoyCohen I just updated my question by including the models, thanks

Comment: your model makes your question more confusing, **not** less. Your second query refers to SecondTable.Id and model doesn't have it. You may need to rethink your model, and rephrase the question

Comment: Hi @Felix I just edited the model again, sorry for the confusion because I just renamed those properties from the actual one.

Comment: @Edward - and now the deficiency of the model is more obvious. There should be relationship between objects, as I describe in my answer

Comment: Hello @Felix maybe I just renamed the models incorrectly from the original one for the sake of confidentiality on the codes. But what I've understood in the implementation is that the ParentId from the FirstTable and Id from the SecondTable are common or have a relationship with each other. Sorry for the confusions.

Comment: @Edward - it's not just Id (although naming consistency would help). There should be navigation properties to implement the relationship (see my example in the answer!)! In relational DB it's not just the names of the columns - there is Foreign Key constraint to enforce one-to-many relationship. EF also needs to have the implementation of the relationship between objects

Comment: In general instead of `xyz.Count()==0` you should use `!xyz.Any()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var parentIds =  _context.Set<FirstTable>()
        .Where(a => a.IsActive
            && a.BatchId.Equals(batchId)
            && a.Source.Equals(source)).Select(b => new { b.parentId });


var risks = await (from s in  _context.Set<SecondTable>()
             join p in parentIds on s.Id equals p.parentId
             join r in _context.Set<SecondTable>() on s.IdNumber equals r.IdNumber
             select r).GroupBy(r=>r.IdNumber)
                       .Select(r=> r.OrderByDescending(risk =>risk.EndorsementNumber).FirstOrDefault())
            .ToArrayAsync();
   return risks;
```

You can have 1 query instead of 3. It will perform better as the number of the rows from the first query grows.

**EDIT:** As @SvyatoslavDanyliv mentioned in the comments, group-take operations may not work depending on the version of the EF and the provider you use. You may need to separate the query and the group by operation like below :

```
var result = await (from s in  _context.Set<SecondTable>()
                 join p in parentIds on s.Id equals p.parentId
                 join r in _context.Set<SecondTable>() on s.IdNumber equals r.IdNumber
                 select r).ToArrayAsync();

var risks = result.GroupBy(r=>r.IdNumber)
                  .Select(r=> r.OrderByDescending(
                           risk =>risk.EndorsementNumber).FirstOrDefault())
            .ToArray();
                
return risks;
```

Comment: I would strongly argue against `join` in LINQ statements. If you need to use `join`, then something is wrong with your model. If you have navigation properties, you don't need joins

Comment: @Felix If the models and navigation properties are known yes I would think like you and also you can't always have navigation properties, or using navigation properties won't give you the desired behavior, so there will be times that you need those ugly joins.

Comment: @Eldar, it will not work. GroupBy has a limitation and you cannot access to it’s items.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it depends on the provider and the version of the EF. But I made many queries like this and they had no problem.

Comment: @Eldar, It will work only with EF Core 2.x and only because it will load whole table to the client. I have answered about 10 times in SO about this limitation. If you know SQL try to create such GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, queries 1-3 can and should be combined. In order to do that you need, to have navigation properties in your model. It seems that there is one-to-many relationship between FirstTable and SecondTable. Let's use Customer and Order instead.

```
class Customer {
    int CustomerId
    string BatchId
    ICollection<Order> Orders
}

class Order {
    int OrderId
    int CustomerId
    Customer Customer
    Risk Risk
}
```

in which case you just write third query as

```
List<Risk> = await _context.Orders.Where(o => o.Customer.BatchId == batchId)
    .Select(o => o.Risk).ToListAsync();
```

Obviously, I am only guessing the structure and the relationship. But hopefully, this can get you started. For me `Contains()` is "code smell". There is a high chance that there will be large list out of your first query, and contains() will produce a huge `IN` clause in the database, that can easily crash the system

Comment: Whoever is trying to add semicolon at the end of the statements... I left them out *intentionally*. In reality, you also need `{get; set;}` - this is only a guess of the model, and not intended to be copy and pasted